# Resolve Local Maven Project as Dependency in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-dependency

I have two maven Projects call them as **MainProject** and **DependnecyProject**.  I use **DependnecyProject** functions in the **MainProject** project which means **DependnecyProject** is a dependency for **MainProject** Project.

**MainProject** pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>DependnecyProject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In my local eclipse, this is completely perfect and the execution doesn't have any problem.

I have both of these Projects in Git and I have two Jobs created in Jenkins named **Main** and **Dependency**. I have a Pre Step in the **Main** job to build the **Dependency** first and then build **Main**.

**Dependency** job is successful but the **Main** job is failing saying the dependency mentioned above (**DependnecyProject**) cannot be resolved. This can be understood as the Jenkins and Maven is not able to find the dependency. Is there a way to make sure the Jenkins resolve the dependency?

Alternately, I have tried one more solution
In My Local, I have tried to use in **MainProject** POM.XML

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>DependnecyProject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Users\cpratap\New-Workspace\Child\target\Parent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

which is working perfectly in local, but not sure how to make it work the same in the Jenkins?

**Update:**
In the Jenkins Main job, I did below configuration (as suggested by @Ian W). Though it is a poor work around as mentioned, this really worked.

1. Followed the same configuration
2. In the **Main** Jenkins job, I have three Pre-Steps
3. One Pre-Step is to trigger the **Dependency** Job
4. Second Pre-Step is to copy the artifacts from **Dependency** to **Main**
5. Third Pre-Step is to install the Dependency into the local repo using "Invoke Top Level Maven Targets" and used below in Goal
   install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=jar

This completely solved my problem and I could run the build and run my test cases without any issues. Thank you all for the support

Comment: Can you show how the maven jobs look like? The artifact (jar) must be available in the local repository, otherwise the main project build will always fail. I see the jar of dependency project is created, so the main project can point to it, and that's why it succeeds when using the second case where you define the full path. Did you at least define "install" goal in DependencyProject Maven job?

Comment: Usually, you use a Maven repository manager where you _deploy_ your artifacts to. That way, no environment is forced to _install_ dependencies first.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose That's right. However, he defined two different jobs, launched separately, that means that the main project's build must have somehow all dependencies available to succeed, and one way to do that they have to be installed in the local repository.

Comment: Use a repository manager. Don't try to share local repositories between builds, they are not thread safe.

Comment: @MarcoTizzano That is one way to do it, but not a good one. Each developer - for example - that checks out the main project has to do these setup steps first, which is not appropriate.

Comment: The two jobs must both use the same node/agent and not a private repo. The first job must use target "install" to publish to the local repo. You should not need to specify "scope" or "systemPath". But a proper repo mgr is preferred.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes i am aware and I agree that the best practice would be to use a repository manager. However, the question was another, and it is focused on Maven, not an additional tool. I just want to answer the question and help to sort the issue out. Of course, if he wants to use a repositoty manager, that it's even better.

Comment: @IanW you got exactly what I meant to do :)

Comment: A (poor) workaround would be to have the provider job archiveArtifacts. The consumer job can use [copyartifact plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) to  retrieve into workspace, then [mvn install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) to add to the local repo.

Comment: Don't use system scope.    Are the two projects in any way related on the file system level, or do you have two checkouts in Eclipse in the same workspace?

Answer (score -2):

If you put a jar in vcs along with you source code, then the way to do that is to declare you repository in you pom.xml file, and use you jar as a dependency.

For example, if you put your jar to lib directory of you projects, that's how you use it in you project. Suppose you jar name is hello-world-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, you want your groupId to be **com.local** , your artifactId **hello-world-library-local** and version is **1.0-SNAPSHOT**

First you should create local repository in your project's directory and put your jar there.

```sh
mvn \
deploy:deploy-file \
-Durl=file:./lib \
-Dfile=hello-world-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
-DgroupId=com.local \
-DartifactId=hello-world-library-local \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Then add local repository to you pom.xml

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>localrep</id>
        <name>local repository</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And then, add you jar as a dependency to dependencies block in your pom.xml file

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.local</groupId>
            <artifactId>hello-world-library-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

You can use that if you want to distribute you jar with your source code and don't want to mess with your project's  setting every time you're building on a new machine.

But this is not recommended to use in enterprise environment. You **NEVER** put repository block in your pom.xml, unless that's your toy project, or your really know what you are doing

If you don't want to copy your jar to your project's directory every time, you should consider **converting your projects to a single multi module maven project**.

Comment: Adding a binary to a repo is a really bad idea, especially if part of a CI build job. It will blow up the size of yout repo size since every binary commit is a whole new copy. Modify 1 char in your source add x MB to your repo. Heck, every build would add an identical copy w/new MANIFST.MF w/updated timestamp! Also, a milti-module maven project suggests OP'd always build both all the time, when it's probably not the intent. With respect, checking in binaries is an anti-pattern and should never be recommended; that's how bad practices are born and perpetuated. Suggest deleting answer.

Comment: That's all true, if you update your jar every time you build your project. But if you do it rarely, the problem with new copies of the binary for every commit doesn't exist. And for toy projects it's fine, because it teaches you how to decompose your code leaving the burden of working with artifact repository. Never do it in production though.  If you need to update the library frequently, multi maven project is way. So if after reading that ,you still think I should delete my answer, I will gladly do so

Comment: @IanW This is why reproducible builds are good, and Maven has been taught to do them - http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-reproducible-builds.html